# convert a Class attribute to Field

Tags: java, field

Can I convert a `Class` attribute to appropriate `Field` [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)?

For example consider the following code:

```
class Test {
    Integer A;

    void init() {
        Field fA = ???;
    }
}
```

I want `fA` to describe `Test.A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Field fA = Test.class.getDeclaredField("A");
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not converting `A` to a `Field` unless you give me an approach to convert `A` to `"A"` :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Looking for a function (or multiple lines of code) which converts `A` to `fA`. Your methods converts `A` name (which is `"A"`) to 'fA'. Can I get 'A's name by any means?

Comment: I get that. I meant for what purpose? Maybe there is an easier way that you are not looking into

Comment: I asked my problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897150/log-all-the-attribute-changes-of-a-class