# log all the attribute changes of a Class

Tags: java

For debugging purposes I need to keep track of a `Class` attributes changes.

For example consider the following class:

```
class Test {
    int myInt;
    String myString;
    ...

    public void setMyInt(int a) ...
    public void setMyString(String s) ...

    public printDebugLog();
}

void main() {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.setMyInt(5);
    t.setMyString("Hello");
    t.printDebugLog();
}
```

I want to output to be something like:

```
myInt => 5
myString => Hello
```

The easy solution is to create logs instantly. i.e. adding a `Log` function as follow:

```
void Log(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

and then code the *set* functions like below:

```
void setMyString(String s) {
    myString = s;
    Log("myString => " + s);
}
```

this requires all the *set* functions to be written variously and I wonder if there are any **better** solution for such matter. For example it might be easier (if possible) to create a `SetValue` function which accepts two variables and set the first attribute to the value of the second object. or something like this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you should wrap your class with orthogonal code that performs logging.

Since your class does not implement interface you cannot use dynamic proxy, so you have to use one of solutions that use byte code engineering.

The strongest solution I know is AspectJ. But probably you even do not need it. You can use Javassist or CGLIb - the byte code engineering libraries that allow creating proxies that wrap classes, so you can add code that performs logging.

Comment: With employing the **[factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)**, or the **[abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)** pattern to create object instances in your code, this should be a pretty easy job...

Comment: I believe that your answer (adding AOP) is much more than what we need here. I wonder if I can use a more simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AOP to intercept the setter methods and log when they are called. A quick google should give you a few examples.

Answer (score -3):

If you debug via JPDA,
you can create a Breakpoint 
on a field you like to watch.

Comment: The question asked for the ability to log changes, not the ability to interactively view via debugger. Very different use cases.

Comment: Initial intent is to debug. Logging is just @MZB's prefered way.