# keep track of an instance attributes changes

Tags: java, class, attributes, rmi

We are working on a multi process projects which use RMI for RPCs.

The problem that we are facing is that the main object which must be passed between processes is very big (when serialized), and this dropped the performance of the code dramatically.

Since, none of the processes change the whole object and only alter small parts of it, we decided to just pass "the modifications" through RMI.

but I found no proper way to implement such concept. The first idea was to keep track of all changes of the main instance. But this seems not easy according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897150/log-all-the-attribute-changes-of-a-class).

I need a way which we can:

- develop fast
- performs fast

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Just make this 'main object' a remote object that implements a remote interface, and export it, instead of serializing it backwards and forwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to customize your serialization so you will be able to send only the changes. you can do it by implementing private method of
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) and of course also readObject from the other side. well, what you should do in this functions?
I suggest you will manage a bitmap of all the members that were changed and only send them in the serialization, just change the unchanged members to null send the object in serialization and than return there values. in the other side read the bitmap and than you will know how to

Answer (score -1):

First time you need to pass the whole object.

Use PropertyChangeListener on the object, this would generate an PropertyChangeEvent.

You can pass the PropertyChangeEvent around. It has the getSource(), by which you can identify the object. If this is not enough, if you need IOR or any other sort of reference, create a wrapper and sent it across..

-Maddy

Comment: may I ask for more info on "PropertyChangeListener" please?
a sample code would be great :)

Comment: I dont know how exactly you are sending rhe big object. But, I can tell you that you need to follow the same procedure to send PrroperyChangeEvent/wrapper.. For this your object's class needs ro extend ProprtyChangeListener and overwrite onPropeeyChange method.. In this method you need RMI invocation...

Comment: I really find no way to use ProprtyChangeListener. a simple code maybe? thanks.

Comment: PropertyChangeListener is not a remote interface, so this suggestion cannot possibly work.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

```
public class Test {
    PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        String oldName = this.name;
        this.name = name;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        int oldAge = this.age;
        this.age = age;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("age", oldAge, age);

    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public Test(){

    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Test myTestObject = new Test();
        myTestObject.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPropertyChangeListener());
        myTestObject.setAge(12);
        myTestObject.setName("Rick");
        myTestObject.setName("Andrew");
    }
    private static class MyPropertyChangeListener implements  PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            String clazz = event.getSource().getClass().getName();
            System.out.println(clazz+"::"+event.getPropertyName()+" changed from "+event.getOldValue()+" to "+event.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example but using this approach you can create different PropertyChangeListeners and provide different logic inside theirs method propertyChange.
Also is possible to fire only the changes over a small set of attributes and not over all of them (not storing the oldValue and not firing the firePropertyChange method of PropertyChangeSupport).

Of course that you can use AOP, but perhaps you are looking for a solution like presented above. I hope this helps.

Comment: PropertyChangeListener is not a remote interface, so this suggestion cannot possibly work.

Comment: Hi @EJP, I understand your point. Assuming that we are trying to mitigate the amount of information that will be send. Assuming that you need to update clients with information that changed in the server; one solution could be send only the changes detected: At server side, use the code proposed and add another class implementing the Remote interface, provide a getChanges method and return a List<Changes> (that will be created with the code proposed above). The Client finally will process the List, using the changes according the project needs. Please let me know if I was not clear.

Comment: @MBZ, did the answer helps you? Please let me know if my post was enough or I need to update it with the comments that I post on Oct 23.

Comment: it can't help anybody. It won't work. If you want your comments of Oct 23 accepted as an answer, post them as an answer, and delete the incorrect parts of your present answer, that is to say all of it.